# Object instantiation order and Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to instantiate two classes like so:

```
ball = new Ball(gc, board, player, ai, score);      
ai = new AiPaddle(gc, ball);
```

My problem is that my Ball class keeps throwing a Null Pointer Exception because I'm passing in ai, which hasn't yet been instantiated.

Reversing the order that these objects are created just makes my AiPaddle class throw the error instead because it needs the ball class.

What is the best way to fix a problem like this? I fixed it by making a new method in my ball class called addAi which takes ai instead so i have this:

```
ball = new Ball(gc, board, player, score);      
ai = new AiPaddle(gc, ball);    
ball.addAi(ai);
```

But I'm sure there is a much better way to do this.

Comment: You have a dependency problem, which is caused by bad design. Rethink the structure of both classes.

Comment: You can design your classes in well manner if you look into the details of their relationship. They may have "has a" or "is a" kind of relationship. If you identify them then you will design better classes and you will able to identify and solve any dependency problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to go would be have a third "master" object which knows about the Ball and the AiPaddle.  Instantiate both ball and ai, and then pass them into the "master".

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Lucas Knuth, you have a design problem. The solution you found is a good one, but don't forget the convention: you are setting a property of the Ball, so you should call the method setAi(), not addAi().

And next time, when you design your classes, try to prevent this problem.